# MySQL - List results sort by same values first ?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the rows firstly displayed which have the same row data with the country (There is a row that named country). For example if there are 5 results and 2 of them have the country of "England", they should came first. I have tried

```
$mycountry = "england";
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members where basresvar='yes' ORDER BY country DESC limit 10")
```

But it doesnt sort the results as I want. What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ORDER BY country = "England" DESC, country
```

When a comparison is true, the value is `1`; when it's false the value is `0`. So when you order by this comparison in descending order, the rows where the country is equal to England will be put first.

Adding a second ordering criteria makes all the remaining countries sort alphabetically after England.

Comment: Curious; is this shorthand syntax similar to fthiella's answer? seems like it. (interesting).

Comment: Yes, it's very similar, it just takes advantage of the fact that MySQL represents booleans as numbers, so you don't have to spell it out with `CASE`.

Comment: Smartest answer. A question, so if I just want to sort the same country ones first, using only ORDER BY country = "England" DESC will do the job, correct ?

Comment: Yes, that will leave all the rest unsorted.

Answer (score 5):

You could write your query this way:

```
select *
from
  members
where
  basresvar='yes'
order by
  case when country='england' then 1 else 2 end
limit 10
```

the `case...when` statement will return 1 when the country='england' and 2 otherwise, then since we are ordering by this statement this will put rows that have country='england' at the top, and others at the bottom.

Comment: You might explain what "case" does / how it works... But nice answer!